# Can I MD5 a column I'm selecting?

Tags: php, mysql

I've done some Google'ing and it's brought up nothing so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to run this query (the language is PHP):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(field1) = '$var'
```

It's not returning any rows,

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.

I've tried some variations such as "SELECT field1 as name FROM table WHERE MD5(name) = '$var'" but it still doesn't work.

EDIT:

I figured it out. A lot of the answers to this question are assuming a lot of things such as 1. it's for a login system (it's for something related, but not for a login system), 2. i'm not hashing my values before saving them in the db (I am, but this certain situation requires me not knowing the plaintext, thus requiring me to MD5 the column in the SQL query).  A lot of these assumptions were made because I simplified the hell out of the example to convey my question. Thank you to those who tried answering.

Comment: You seem to be directly mixing PHP with SQL, which you can't really do.

Comment: What values does `field1` contain? What is the value of `$var`?

Comment: The point to hash the password is that it is not stored in plain text in the database. I don't understand why you'd want to do such thing.

Comment: You only get a result if at least one row matches the `WHERE` condition. Please check that at least one `MD5(field1)` equals the value you've stored into `$var`.

Comment: and don't forget to salt it to.

Comment: It's a dumbed down version of what I'm actually doing so I understand you not seeing the point in this.

And now that I know that you can definitely MD5 columns, I have figured out where my problem is.

Comment: The MD5 function aside, the second variation of the query you listed could never work since you can not use an alias you give the column immediately in the where clause of the same select statement.  In other words `select userid as a from users where a = 'Lamoni'` would never work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, MySQL has a built in MD5 function.

```
<?php
    ...("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MD5(password) = '$password';") or die(...
?>
```

should work fine. If it's not returning any rows then you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to know if MD5'ing columns worked like that, and you gave me the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It would seem that you are MD5ing the wrong value. The password in the DB should not be plain text, it should have been hashed and that value stored. The query as you have it written is hashing a hash then comparing it to the plain text entered by the user. Try this instead -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE password = MD5($password);
```

As Vincent mentioned, it would make sense to hash the password before sending the query to the DB server.

```
$passhash = MD5($password);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE password = $passhash;
```

Comment: But then, wouldn't $password be transferred in clear on the network? It would seem a lot better to calculate the hash in PHP.

Comment: The user enters the password in plain text, you would have to hash the password with javascript client side then pass the hashed value. Hashing it in PHP is already too late, the password has already been transferred in plain text by the time the server gets it.

Comment: Brent Friar: I wasn't clear enough I think. The password goes from the client to the server (you could use SSL to crypt it I assume), but then, if you do such a query, it goes from the server to the database server. I'm wondering if the query will be crypted or not.

Comment: You have to see what else I'm doing (which is irrelevant to the question) to understand why I'm needing this, you can stop discussion on it. I've figured it out. And the password IS hashed in the database.  Again, this is NOT for a login system, but for a "remember me" function.  I apologize for the confusion, but I was attempting to simplify the example used as much as possible to convey my question.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case you could simply calculate the hash before the query is sent. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: Again, I want to state to anyone who stumbles upon this question, I am not hashing the wrong value.  I appreciate the attempt of helping me but this is definitely not the problem. I am correctly storing hashed values and everything, so no worries on that.